# Upgrade latest Hera to Odin

Tags: updates

The problem is as follows: I have Elementary OS 5.1.7. Hera and consider upgrading to OS6. However, so far I have only found information that a direct in-place upgrade is not possible, only a complete reinstallation is planned. Is that true or is there a possibility to upgrade to OS6 in-place? Thank you ronny

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same question, and my question received a few answers, so you may want to read it once, I think.

[How to update from Elementary OS 5.1.7 to Elementary 6](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28515/how-to-update-from-elementary-os-5-1-7-to-elementary-6)

I have also created a discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/elementary/os/discussions/535

TL;DR

Till now, I have seen no options for in-place update like Windows and MacOS.

Sorry for disappointing, but I am also disappointed by this news that there are no in-place updates till now.

Comment: Thank You very much!!!

Comment: Nice to know I could be of help to you!

Comment: I have also created a issue for it on GitHub, so fingers crossed!

Comment: @RolandStrohmaier I received a few more responses on my question,  you can review it here

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28515/how-to-update-from-elementary-os-5-1-7-to-elementary-6

Comment: @RolandStrohmaier One of the person helped as following:

Did you try this https://github.com/meisenzahl/upgrade you will need to build it from source instructions in the repo's readme