# Is there an 'Elementary for Dummies'?

Tags: release-hera, updates, odin

I'm moving from 30 years of MacOS to Elementary. I have almost zero knowledge of the command line. Is there a 'baby steps' guide to upgrading from Elementary 5.x to 6.x

Answer (score 2):

There are already answers to similar questions.

- [Upgrade latest Hera to Odin](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28514/upgrade-latest-hera-to-odin)
- [How to update from Elementary OS 5.1.7 to Elementary 6](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28515/how-to-update-from-elementary-os-5-1-7-to-elementary-6?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- https://github.com/elementary/triage/discussions/122

As I understand it, there is no official way to upgrade from 5 to 6.

I upgraded as described here: https://github.com/elementary/triage/discussions/122#discussioncomment-1192733, I think otherwise there will be some pitfalls.